# get <li> but find only selected things and then iterate next <li> and so on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work on scraping ceneo.pl so i would like to know how can I achieve this mentioned in title.
I typed this code (this is only fragment) (gt means get html text):

```
abc = response.data // this is html source code
gt = $(abc).find('li.product-review.js_product-review').html();                         
findCons = $(gt).find('span.cons-cell').find('ul').text();
findPros = $(gt).find('span.pros-cell').find('ul').text();
findSumUp = $(gt).find('.product-review-body').text();
findStars = $(gt).find('.review-score-count').text();
findReviewer = $(gt).find('div.product-reviewer').text();
```

.
.
.
My question is how can I repeat this what I typed (when I use .each() it displays [object Object] )
I don't have idea how can I put into array this li (from variable gt) element from ceneo.pl
In addition I want to get review in this same site (so all reviews on one site) from li element then next reviews on next sites and so on.

So with .each() it was like this:

```
$http.get(fullUrl).then(function(response){
var abc = response.data;
gt = $(abc).find('li.product-review.js_product-review').html();
liEach = $(gt).each(function(){
findCons = $(gt).find('span.cons-cell').find('ul').text();
findPros = $(gt).find('span.pros-cell').find('ul').text();
findSumUp = $(gt).find('.product-review-body').text();
findStars = $(gt).find('.review-score-count').text();
findReviewer = $(gt).find('div.product-reviewer').text();
if ( findReviewer == null ){
findReviewer.append('anonim');
};
var findReviewDate = $(gt).find("[datetime]").attr('datetime');
var findRecOrNot = $(gt).find('em.product-recommended').text(); 


});
alert(liEach);
```

Comment: don't just tell us what happens in your `each` ..show us. Also provide some relevant html structure. Also we have no idea what `abc` is

Comment: It would help immensely if you provided example input, your expected output, and the code you used to try and achieve that output.

Comment: The code you provided alerts `[object Object]` because thats whats stored in the variable liEach.  liEach is an object that consists of all the DOM elements that match the selector.

Comment: so I must .text()    this?

Comment: @Grisza, no, in fact using `.html()` is giving you the wrong results to begin with.  You don't need to access any of the properties, you want to DOM object itself so you can iterate over it using `.each()`.  See my answer for how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to iterate over the matching DOM objects.  If I run this javascript in the console at ceneo.pl, it iterates over every review and prints each reviewer's name in the console.

```
$(document).find('li.product-review.js_product-review').each(function() {

    findCons = $(this).find('span.cons-cell').find('ul').text();
    findPros = $(this).find('span.pros-cell').find('ul').text();
    findSumUp = $(this).find('.product-review-body').text();
    findStars = $(this).find('.review-score-count').text();
    findReviewer = $(this).find('div.product-reviewer').text();

    console.log(findReviewer)

})
```

With that, you should be able to manipulate the results as you wish.  If you get stuck please provide a more detailed example of what the expected output should be, and what you did to try and achieve it.  We can help troubleshoot it.

Hope that helps! :-)

Edit to add:  If you wanted to build a JSON string with that, here is an example of how you could do it:

```
var json = '';
$(document).find('li.product-review.js_product-review').each(function() {

    //find all the data points
    findCons = $(this).find('span.cons-cell').find('ul').text();
    findPros = $(this).find('span.pros-cell').find('ul').text();
    findSumUp = $(this).find('.product-review-body').text();
    findStars = $(this).find('.review-score-count').text();
    findReviewer = $(this).find('div.product-reviewer').text();


    //build the JSON string, trimming whitespace from the elements
    str = '"cons": "'+findCons.trim()+'",';
    str += '"pros": "'+findPros.trim()+'",';
    str += '"sum": "'+findSumUp.trim()+'",';
    str += '"stars": "'+findStars.trim()+'",';
    str += '"reviewer": "'+findReviewer.trim()+'"';


    //enclose the JSON object
    json += '{' + str + '},'

})


//remove the trailing comma from the last item
json = json.replace(/,+$/,'')

//replace any newline characters with HTML breaks
json = json.replace(/\n/g,'<br />')

//wrap the JSON in a top level element
json = '{"reviews":[' + json + ']}'

//print the completed string
console.log(json)
```

When I run that code in the console at ceneo.pl, it returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "reviews":[
        {
            "cons": "",
            "pros": "dobrze pierze, energooszczędność, spora pojemność, cicha",
            "sum": "Pralkę mam od wczoraj. Podczas prania nie słychać totalnie nic. Siedząc w tym samym pomieszczeniu musiałem sprawdzać czy już skończyła, bo dźwiękiem jej pracy nie da się określić. Podczas wirowania pralka jest stabilna, nawet na najwyższych obrotach. Należy oczywiście pamiętać o dokładnym wypoziomowaniu.<br /><br />Do zabudowy lepszej chyba nie ma. Widziałem pracę droższych modeli, ale Ariston przebija je w 100%<br /><br />Polecam Dwie prewrsze opinie sa bez sensu.. pisane raczej przez tę samą osobębo to opinia z cokupic.pl, ktos wystawil takie same opinie na dwóch serwisach",
            "stars": "5/5",
            "reviewer": "cokupic_anonymouse"
        }, {
            "cons": "",
            "pros": "",
            "sum": "Potwierdzam opinie poprzedniczki. Pralkę mam od wczoraj. Podczas prania nie słychać totalnie nic. Siedząc w tym samym pomieszczeniu musiałem sprawdzać czy już skończyła, bo dźwiękiem jej pracy nie da się określić. Podczas wirowania pralka jest stabilna, nawet na najwyższych obrotach. Należy oczywiście pamiętać o dokładnym wypoziomowaniu.<br /><br />Do zabudowy lepszej chyba nie ma. Widziałem pracę droższych modeli, ale Ariston przebija je w 100%<br /><br />Polecam",
            "stars": "3/5",
            "reviewer": "Janek"
        }, {
            "cons": "BRAK",
            "pros": "BARDZO CICHA, POJEMNA",
            "sum": "Dla również rewelacja. Dośc długo czekałam na swoją, ale było warto. Jest rewelacyjna. Zgadzam się z resztą użytkowników, jest suuuuuuper cicha!!!Fakt przy odpompywaniu ją słychac, ale to nie jest jej wadą. Bardzo pojemna, dobra dla dużej rodzinki, pary czy singli. Ma funkcje codziennego prania, dzięki której nie trzeba czekac, aż nazbieram ubranka do prania. BAAAAARDZO POLECAM! Warta swojej ceny :-)",
            "stars": "5/5",
            "reviewer": "D."
        }, {
            "cons": "Archaiczny wyglad,brak wyswietlacza (np. pozostaly czas prania)",
            "pros": "Bezszelestna, mnogosc programow, dosc szybkie wirowanie, opoznienie startu",
            "sum": "Bardzo cicha pralka - zgadzam sie z poprzednikami. Wyglad nieco archaiczny ale w tej cenie nie ma wielkiego wyboru. Mam ja dwa miesiace i na razie pracuje bez zarzutu.",
            "stars": "4/5",
            "reviewer": "ELF 31"
        }, {
            "cons": "awaryjność<br />brak wyświetlacza czasu pracy",
            "pros": "cicha<br />dopóki działała prała dobrze<br />dużo programów","sum": "Mam tą pralkę od 2 lat i tydzień temu zaczęła wariować, wodę pobiera ale potem stop, bez prania działa, z praniem nie. Gwarancja się skończyła, dwie firmy już odmówiły mi podjęcia próby naprawy bo do końca nie potrafią stwierdzić źródła problemu a nie chcą mnie naciągać na nieprzewidziane koszty...lekka załamka",
            "stars": "1,5/5",
            "reviewer": "Piotr"
        }, {
            "cons": "brak wyświetlacza czasu pracy",
            "pros": "cicha",
            "sum": "Pralka do zabudowy, bardzo cicha, dobrze pierze, wirowanie nawet na 800 - to wyjęcie niemal suchego prania :) także psisuje sie na medal.<br /><br />Jedynym mankamentem jest brak wtświetlacza ile czasu do końca prania... a i jak dl amnie - bardoz długie programy. Niby sa te na 30 min. nawte na 15 min. ale jeśli włozy się skporo rzeczy pralka je warzy mierzy i tak dostaosowuje program. DLa mnei to minus, jesli chce odświezyć ubrania (nie brudzę sie jak dziecko, nie plamię ubrań) to nie mogę włączyć na 30 min bo przy załadunku normalnym pranie trwa cyba jakies 2 godziny, troche nasakraaaa. Żeby uprać w programie tym 30 min 15 min- chyba trzeba włożyc jedna, diwe rzeczy, BEZSENSSS.Program 15 minut - max wsad 1,5 kg, program 30 minut - max wsad 3 kg - jak dla nas wystarcza w zupełności, ale to prawda - brakuję jakiegoś programu około 60 minutowego..., ale póki co mieszkamy we dwójkę i jest w sam raz.",
            "stars": "3/5",
            "reviewer": "Katarzyna"
        }, {
            "cons": "",
            "pros": "",
            "sum": "po trzech latach po pralce-łożyska do wymiany-niestety przy okazji trzeba wymienić bęben-koszt ok.700 zl",
            "stars": "1/5",
            "reviewer": "jaj"
        }, {
            "cons": "",
            "pros": "cicha",
            "sum": "Mam tą pralkę w zabudowie w kuchni od 3,5 lat. Jestem BARDZO zadowolona. Pralka rzeczywiście cicha, nie kolebie się pod blatem. Bardzo wygodne i moje ulubione programy 15 min i 30 min. W pozostałych programach, np. do bawełny też super pierze - widać to dobrze po ręczniakach i pościeli. Udało mi się nawet bez szwanku wyprać puchową kurteczkę. Naprawdę polecam zwłaszcza do zabudowy.",
            "stars": "5/5",
            "reviewer": "Halina"
        }, {
            "cons": "",
            "pros": "",
            "sum": "witam.<br /><br />pralkę mam ponad dwa lata i zaraz po zakończeniu gwarancji, dosłownie kilka miesięcy, awaria pompy. Podobno zrobiła się jakaś dziurka i woda poszła na uzwojenie co dało zwarcie. Niestety po zmianie pompy lawinowo mechanizm blokady drzwi zaczął szwankować, po drugim dniu naprawy stanęło, że pralki są zbyt nowe i część trzeba zamawiać. (chodzi o blokadę bo pompa od pralek boscha też doskonale pasuje i się sprawuje).<br /><br />na szczęście programator podobno sprawny, bo tak to koszt ok 500 zł. <br /><br />Z pralki jestem bardzo zadowolona i nie chcę jej wymieniać, a tym wszystkim którzy chcecie ją kupić doradzam zakup tylko dam dobrą radę: cokolwiek kupujecie z elektroniki do domu, bierzcie max gwarancję i dokupujcie dodatkową. Są różne sytuacje a szukanie pozornych oszczędności czasem się po prostu nie opłaca.",
            "stars": "4,5/5",
            "reviewer": "nata"
        }, {
            "cons": "",
            "pros": "pojemna",
            "sum": "Pralka solidnie wykonana, bardzo pojemna. Prosta w obsłudze dzięki panelowi , który został opisany w czytelny sposób. Ogólnie polecam",
            "stars": "5/5",
            "reviewer": "Daniel"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit to answer the question about accessing the cons property from the JSON:

To access the object properties, you can use jQuery's parseJSON function.

```
var jsonStr = '{"reviews":[{"cons": "example con1","pros": "example pro1","sum": "example sum1","stars": "5/5","reviewer": "example reviewer1"},{"cons": "example con2","pros": "example pro2","sum": "example sum2","stars": "5/5","reviewer": "example reviewer2"}]}'


var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonStr );
for(var i = 0; i < obj.reviews.length; i++) {
    alert( obj.reviews[i].cons );
}
```

Remember, reviews is an array, so you'll need to iterate over all of its elements to access all the review data.

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2h51epm/1/

Comment: I want to achieve this: get review with each reviewer, so I have in the table cons pros etc. with each reviewer of product but when I want to get li it displays in one row "stack" of reviewers sumups cons pros
I want to have consistent data like on the page

Comment: Ok, the each() loop is already getting those values.  What do you want to do with the data that .each() is retrieving?  What is the desired format of your output?  JSON object, array, HTML table, etc?  Clearly explain how you want it to be structured.

Comment: I want to put this text into firstly HTML table to watch output then to JSON object so I can then pass through ajax to php to sql to insert into database how?

Comment: How?  By building the JSON string and HTML table inside the .each() loop.  What code have you tried?

Comment: I mean this text or variable findCons what I got for example
gj = {wady:findCons};
JSON.stringify(gj);
inside this each loop no but after
I have HTML table builded with js and there with use array reviewText where I have var findCons
i.e var reviewText = [findCons, findPros, findSumUp, findStars, findReviewer];

Comment: You'd need to build that JSON string inside the .each().  I'll add another example.

Comment: Thank you very much I believe this is very useful!
I did trimming but with weak results

Comment: how to access to cons?
json.reviews.cons doesn't work
JSON.parse - throw error with bad character
so I try eval()
What I try doesn't work help :|

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of how to access the object properties, including cons.  Hope that helps!